# Google Drive API permissions, how to disable findable by anyone on Internet?

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client, pydrive

I search for google but get no result, my code is as follow:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

# this function used inside function do_the_work(drive)
def upload_gd(media_file, drive):
    print 'Try uploading ' + media_file

    xfile = drive.CreateFile()
    xfile.SetContentFile(media_file)
    xfile.Upload()
    print('Created file %s with mimeType %s' % (xfile['title'], xfile['mimeType']))

    permission = xfile.InsertPermission({
        'type': 'anyone',
        'value': 'anyone',
        'role': 'reader'})

    print 'Sharable link (to view) is:' + xfile['alternateLink']
    print 'Get direct link'
    file_id = xfile['alternateLink'].split('/')[-2]
    print 'file ID: ' + file_id
    d_link = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=' + file_id
    print 'Direct link is: ' + d_link

    return d_link

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()

drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
do_the_work(drive)
```

And, the permissions I get for the file is:

[image: Anyone can find and view]

But, I only want anyone can view, but not findable as:

[image: anyone can view]

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `withLink` field:

```
permission = xfile.InsertPermission({'type': 'anyone',
                                     'value': 'anyone',
                                     'role': 'reader',
                                     'withLink': True})  # <-- This field.
```

For all possible settings have a look at the API reference: [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert) (PyDrive currently uses API v2)

And as an aside, you can get the ID of `xfile` with `xfile['id']` so you don't need to split the alternate link.

All fields listed [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource) can be accessed using `xfile['<property name>']` after you call `xfile.FetchMetadata(fetch_all=True)`. Using this you can extract the different types of file links from the file object, which will be more robust then your current method of achieving this.

Comment: Note that, pydrive is currently using drive api v2

Comment: Yep, thank you @BùiVănThủ for highlighting this. The link specified above links to v2 - I edited the post to make this clear :)

Answer (score 0):

```
permission = xfile.InsertPermission({'type': 'anyone',
                                     'value': 'anyone',
                                     'role': 'reader'})
```

With that statement you are essentially setting the file to public read only.  Public read only is readable by everyone on the internet.

**Answer**: If you don't want to anyone on the internet to be able to find or view it then set type to `group`, `domain`, or `user` or better yet set value to the email address of the person you whish to be able to view the file.